# open62541 Visual Studio 2017 error, OPCUA

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, opc-ua, open62541

I am trying to build open62541, generate files for VS 2017, using Cmake.
I am having problem,

```
"MSB6006 'cmd.exe' exited with code 1 error " for open62541 files. 
When I build the generated file from Cmake, using VS2017.
```

I am trying to connect my 4Diac control system to UA expert, which will be used to read and write data to JS simulator.
I am looking for answers but have not found any satisfactory answers. 
I will really appreciate some solution.

Thank you.
BR, 
Ahsan

Comment: Possibly build was not successful with few warnings or you can try rebuilding with different flag configuration in cmake.